# NSLog giving me warnings which are not correctable

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nslog, format-specifiers

I have the following line of code in my Mac OS X application:

```
NSLog(@"number of items: %ld", [urlArray count]);
```

And I get the warning: "Format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')"

However, if I change my code to:

```
NSLog(@"number of items: %u", [urlArray count]);
```

I get the warning:

Format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')

So then I change it to

```
NSLog(@"number of items: %u", [urlArray count]);
```

but I get the warning:
Format specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')

How can I set up my NSLog so it does not generate a warning? If I follow Xcode's suggestions i just get into in an endless loop of changing the format specifier but the warnings never go away.

Answer (score 14):

Yeah this is annoying. It is a 32/64 bit thing I believe. The easiest thing to do is just cast to a long:

```
NSLog(@"number of items: %lu", (unsigned long)[urlArray count]);
```

Answer (score 6):

The [portability guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for universal applications suggest casting in this case.

```
NSLog(@"number of items: %ld", (unsigned long)[urlArray count]);
```

Comment: That seems rather unnecessary but it does clear up the warnings.

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference but you should probably case to the same type as the format specifier. So (unsigned long) would be %lu, or (long) would be %ld

Comment: @darren it does make a difference, not doing so is undefined behavior.

Comment: From the portability guide:


Typically, in 32-bit code you use the %d specifier to format int values in functions such as printf, NSAssert, and NSLog, and in methods such as stringWithFormat:. But with NSInteger, which on 64-bit architectures is the same size as long, you need to use the %ld specifier. Unless you are building 32-bit like 64-bit, these specifiers generates compiler warnings in 32-bit mode. To avoid this problem, you can cast the values to long or unsigned long, as appropriate. For example:

NSInteger i = 34;
printf("%ld\n", (long)i);

Answer (score 2):

Another option is mentioned here: [NSInteger and NSUInteger in a mixed 64bit / 32bit environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20362087/445215)

```
NSLog(@"Number is %@", @(number));
```