# NSInteger and NSUInteger in a mixed 64bit / 32bit environment

Tags: ios, objective-c, 64-bit, arm64

I have a fair amount of string format specifiers in NSLog / NSAssert etc. calls which use `%d` and `%u` with `NSInteger (= int on 32bit)` and `NSUInteger (= unsigned int on 32bit)` types respectively.

When converting the app to 64bit, this gives warnings (of course), as `%ld %lu` is expected for what now became a `long` and `unsigned long` type.

Simply converting the format specifiers will of course introduce the reverse warnings in the 32bit build.
So the only solution I see to become warning free is using the 64bit specifiers, and casting to the 64bit value types everywhere a warning is given in the 32bit build.

But I was wondering if perhaps there are format specifiers specifically for the `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger` type which would work on both architectures without casting?

Comment: Can we just disable the warnings?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I think the safest way is to box them into `NSNumber` instances.

```
NSLog(@"Number is %@", @(number)); // use the highest level of abstraction
```

This boxing doesn't usually have to create a new object thanks to [tagged pointer](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html) magic.

If you *really* don't want to use `NSNumber`, you can cast primitive types manually, as others suggested:

```
NSLog(@"Number is %ld", (long)number); // works the same on 32-bit and 64-bit
```

Comment: Why is this "safer" than a cast to long?

Comment: If you insert an explicit cast of `NSUInteger` to `unsigned long` but change it to `NSInteger`, you get incorrect behavior for negative values with no warnings. `@()` is guaranteed to work in all cases.

Comment: And if you cast `NSUInteger` to `long`, you break in cases where `number > ULONG_MAX` (admittedly, this is theoretical, but still, not beautiful).

Comment: @MartinR I think ilya has a point here: Log statements are often quickly introduced for debugging purpose, without considering passed types too much. If there's a way that lets me write the log statement with less thinking, it's a win.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: Yes, I do see the advantage now. I am still reluctant to create an object just for printing an integer, and you lose some features (such as specifying a width %10d or %x for hex output). But yes, for debugging this is a good alternative.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe, tagged pointers are cheap I think (no malloc). Good point about `%10d`. Hex - how about `[NSData dataWithBytes:&number length:sizeof(number)]`?

Comment: After attending the Apple iOS7 Tech Talks, they specifically recommended the casting of these types to (long) and using the appropriate format specifiers when writing code for both 32-bit and 64-bit. This is covered in more detail: https://developer.apple.com/tech-talks/videos/ See the 'Architecting Modern Apps Part 2'

Answer (score 38):

You can also use `%zd` (`NSInteger`) and `%tu` (`NSUInteger`) when logging to the console.

```
NSInteger integer = 1;
NSLog(@"first number: %zd", integer);

NSUInteger uinteger = 1;
NSLog(@"second number: %tu", uinteger);
```

[Also to be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405006/nslog-specifier-for-nsinteger)

Comment: +1 This should be the best. From wikipedia z: For integer types, causes printf to expect a size_t-sized integer argument.

Answer (score 4):

*No*, (unfortunately) there is no printf format that directly corresponds to `NS(U)Integer`.
So for architecture independent code, you have to convert everything to the "long"
variant (as the Xcode "Fix-it" suggests):

```
NSInteger i = ...;
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)i);
```

The only alternative that I know of is from [Foundation types when compiling for arm64 and 32-bit architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848716/foundation-types-when-compiling-for-arm64-and-32-bit-architecture):

```
// In the precompiled header file:
#if __LP64__
#define NSI "ld"
#define NSU "lu"
#else
#define NSI "d"
#define NSU "u"
#endif

NSInteger i = ...;
NSLog(@"i=%"NSI, i);
```

using preprocessor macros (but even the author of that answer calls it a
"admittedly awful approach").

Comment: Nice. This is what `<inttypes.h>` does for the standard types.