# What does @() mean in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

For example,

```
CABasicAnimation *rotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
[rotate setToValue:@(M_PI)];
[rotate setDuration:0.1f];            
[[aView layer] addAnimation:rotate forKey:@"myRotationAnimation"];
```

where `M_PI` is defined as a macro in `math.h`,

```
#define M_PI  3.14159265358979323846264338327950288   /* pi */
```

Comment: @(M_PI) is a NSNumber in this situation

Comment: @johnMa In fact, prefixing with @(expression), where the @ is followed by round brackets, will always be a number right? Square brackets = array, curly brackets = dictionary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a pointer to an `NSNumber` object. It's called a **boxed literal**, because the mental picture is of putting a **primitive value** of expression inside into a "box", that is, an object.

See [official documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) if in doubt. Note that pointer can be to a "real" `NSNumber` object or it can (theoretically, don't know whether this will work in practice) be a **tagged pointer** (see, e.g., [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362406/tagged-pointers-in-objective-c)).

Note that you can also do things like `@"string"` and `@5`, which will create constants in compile time. But you need parentheses to use something which is not a literal, e.g. `@(2 + 3)`. Parentheses form can be used for any expression, even those that compiler cannot compute at compile-time (although if it can, it will just put an expression result into code).

Answer (score 7):

NeXT and Apple `Obj-C` runtimes have long included a short-form way to create new strings, using the literal syntax `@"a new string"`. Using this format saves the programmer from having to use the longer initWithString or similar methods when doing certain operations.

When using Apple LLVM compiler 4.0 or later, arrays, dictionaries, and numbers (`NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSNumber` classes) can also be created using literal syntax instead of methods. Literal syntax uses the `@` symbol combined with [], {}, (), to create the classes mentioned above, respectively.

So, basically it's not only for `id` or `NSNumber` object!

thanks to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C).

Comment: Just wanted to add that `@"string"` is a construction that creates `NSString` literal at compile-time; `@(expression)` or `@[items]` box at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

**It's Shorthand writing**

In Objective-C, any `character`, `numeric` or `boolean` literal prefixed with the `'@'` character will evaluate to a pointer to an `NSNumber object` (In this case), initialized with that value. C’s type suffixes may be used to control the size of `numeric` literals.

`'@'` is used a lot in the objective-C world. It is mostly used to avoid taking english words and making them reserved (for example, you can't have a variable called float in C/Objective-C because this is a reserved word).

Use [this link To have detailed knowledge of '@' symbol](http://guides.macrumors.com/Objective-C_Tutorial#The_.40_symbol).

In Modern Objective C, '@' symbol is used extensively.

**What You can do with it:**

- calculate an expression: `@(<Expression>)`
- wrap any value like int,bool,float,char in same way

**Reasons to use:**

- Easy to write, Less code required
- Less chances of mistakes. Compare `[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]` with `@3`.
- Get rid of typecasting issues in simple cases.

Comment: Minor note: this is not a literal prefixed with `@`. Literal would be something like `@3.14`. This is boxed expression. That's why it needs parentheses.

Comment: @ilyan. Yeah right. But I was trying to give a generic answer. I intended to tell PO why exactly '@' symbol is being used in Objective C. So I started with Literals & ended with expressions. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: It doesn't need parentheses, @ilya; try it. `@M_PI` compiles fine, because the preprocessor has put a literal in before the compiler gets to it. If it were a variable instead of a macro, you would need parentheses.

Comment: Didn't mean to nag, just so that people know this is the reason why arrays cannot be specified as a compile-time initializers.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: indeed! I started thinking about more complicated expressions, sorry.

Comment: Yes; if it wasn't a macro, you would need parentheses, @ilya.

Comment: @ilyan. Arrays can be … See this @[@1,@2] . Works absolutely fine

Comment: @achievelimitless, yes, I'm saying that array or number is created dynamically, so in any place that expects a *compile-time* initializer, will produce an error (try `NSArray *array = @[@1, @2];` **in a global scope**), while `NSString *string = @"string";` works. Admittedly, a fine point.

Answer (score 0):

It represent **id Object**

that you can use any expression in it or return any object.

Syntax :     **@(<#expression#>)** it will return id object.

So in your case it will returning `NSNumber` object to `setToValue` method.

Comment: There is no such thing as an `id` object; by definition any object has a class.

Comment: "an id type can hold a pointer to any object" I believe would be a better expression. Again, `@(something)` construction only creates `NSNumber` instances.