# iOS converting value in NSDictionary with (int) fail

Tags: ios, int, type-conversion

I had a NSDictionary contains 2 key/value pairs:

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{@"tag":@2,                //NSNumber
                      @"string":@"someString"}; //NSString

NSLog(@"%i",(int)[dic objectForKey:@"tag"]);      //print out 34
NSLog(@"%i",[dic objectForKey:@"tag"] intValue]); //print out 2
```

Why does "converting `id` value to `int` with `(int)`"get me the wrong result but not the other way? are they in different levels of conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does "converting id value to int with (int)"get me the wrong result but not the other way? are they in different levels of conversion?

`id` is a pointer type. `id` pointers point to Objective-C objects in memory. By casting `id` to `(int)`, you are merely reinterpreting (some of) the pointer's bit pattern as an `int`, which is quite meaningless. You have to call the proper conversion methods of `NSString` and `NSNumber` if you want to reliably get the primitive values out of the Objective-C object.

**If** you ever seemingly get the "correct" value of `2` in the case of pointer-casting with `NSNumber`, that *may be* because the Objective-C runtime makes use of an optimization technique called [tagged pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362406/tagged-pointers-in-objective-c), whereby small objects are not really created and allocated, but their semantics (the number's bits which the `NSNumber` object stores) is stuffed into the unused bits of the pointer.

Comment: totally worth the lost reps to have this answer !

Answer (score 1):

`@2` is not an `int` but a `NSNumber` you can't cast an `NSNumber` into an `int`. You have to use `intValue` method to get the correct result.

Comment: how does "(int)obj" and "[obj intValue]" considered different?

Comment: @sharky101 in every possible way.

Comment: `(int)obj` is a cast, it'll always return an int since obj is a pointer, but it won't be the intValue of the NSNumber.

Answer (score 0):

The method objectForKey: returns a pointer to the NSNumber object @2, not the value stored in the object itself. So you're typecasting the pointer, not the value 2. In the last line you don't typecast the object but you access a property called intValue which returns the value of the object expressed as an int.

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary contains Object with Key value pairs,but you passed int(@2) into object

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{@"tag":@2,                //NSNumber
                      @"string":@"someString"};
```

so Change int to NSNumber like

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{@"tag":[NSNumber numberWithInt:2];,@"string":@"someString"};
```

and you can get it..

```
int number = [[dict objectForKey:@"tag"] intValue];
```