# What's the internal structure of self?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why can self be used in implementation methods, or in class methods? What's the internal structure of self? eg:

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person
+ (void)initialize
{
    [super initialize];
    [self setupModel];
}
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self test];
    }
    return self;
}
+ (void)setupModel
{
    NSLog(@"setup a person object");
}
- (void)test
{
    NSLog(@"this method is called");
}
@end
```

Code run results:
2018-09-17 09:32:40.615578+0800 Test[662:301213] setup a person object
2018-09-17 09:32:40.615662+0800 Test[662:301213] this method is called

[Code run results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPHgD.png)

Comment: If `self` is used in a class method, doing `[ClassName otherClassMethod]` is the same as `[self otherClassMethod]` But to clarify, you might want to show also what are your code/called and the logs produced (in copy/pasted, not screenshot)

Comment: Please don't post text as a picture. Copy and paste the text of your code run results into your question as text. It's much easier to read, reference, search, and post.

Answer (score 2):

For instance methods, `self` is a reference to the current object.
For class methods, `self` is a reference to the current class.

If you declare an Objective-C method like this

```
- (void)doSomethingWithObject:(id)object { ... }
```

the compiler basically just turns it into a a C function with the following signature:

```
void _i_classname_doSomethingWithObject_(const id self, const SEL _cmd, id object) { ... }
```

(where classname is the name of the class the method belongs to. for class methods, the `i` becomes a `c`)

When you call the method `[foo doSomethingWithObject:bar]`, the compiler turns that method call into a call to [`objc_msgSend`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1456712-objc_msgsend), which "forwards" the call to the correct implementation:

```
objc_msgSend(foo, @selector(doSomethingWithObject:), bar);
```

As you can see, the parameters passed to `objc_megSend` are the same expected by the C function containing the implementation of the Objective-C method.

Comment: What's the bottom layer of self, is it a structure? @Lukas

Comment: @li.cheng pretty much, yeah. `self` has the same "structure" as any other instance of an objc class. basically, all classes are C structs w/ a so called `isa` pointer pointing to the object's class. (see this guide for more information: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html )

Answer (score 1):

These are implementation details, so you shouldn't rely on them:

`self` is either a [tagged pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362406/tagged-pointers-in-objective-c) or a genuine pointer to an struct that starts with the `isa` field and then contains all of the object's instance variables.

The `isa` field is itself either a [set of bitfields](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2013/09/24/objc_explain_Non-pointer_isa.html) that contains the instance's retain contain, some flags, and a pointer to the `Class` of the instance, or (on older and 32-bit platforms) it is just a pointer to the `Class` of the instance (in which case the retain count is stored in a global hash table).